# How do i strip the full path retaining only the filename?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, du

I am using the following find command to list all the files recursively within a folder and sort it by size ( higest size being on top )

`find . -not -path '*/\.*' -not -name '*.nfo' -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h`

The command is working well but i need to strip off the full path from each result only retaining the filename
Eg.
`Dir/AnotherDir/file.mp4 should be listed as file.mp4`

Generally when i have to do this in find command , i simply use `-printf '%f\n'` but this is can't be used in my current command as the files are being printed by du command

Comment: [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename): Print NAME with any leading directory components removed

Comment: I am aware of this command but how it use it alongside du command ?

Comment: Or pipe the output to sed: `... | sed -e 's@.*/@@'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just post process the data:

```
find ... | sort ... | sed -E 's@[[:space:]].*/@ @'
```

or

```
... | awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $NF}' FS='\t\|/'
```

Comment: Hello , i just now tried this solution but along with the directory structure , it also strips off the size which du comands adds at start of each line. Can you please make your sed command not touch the size info

Comment: Probably easiest to just match the whitespace. Edited.

Comment: Of course now you have to worry about whitespace in the filenames, so maybe easier to match the hard tab.  It's going to be very difficult to handle newlines in any filenames, though, so it's really not worth worrying about whitespace.